# Unable to install Microsoft.Maui.Essentials

Tags: maui

I tried to install Microsoft.Maui.Essentials Latest stable 8.0.3 in my Visual studio 2022 .NET 7.0, and I am facing this kind of error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1605  Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: Xamarin.Google.Crypto.Tink.Android from 1.10.0 to 1.7.0.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 SpeechToText -> Microsoft.Maui.Essentials 8.0.3 -> Xamarin.Google.Crypto.Tink.Android (>= 1.10.0) 
 SpeechToText -> Xamarin.Google.Crypto.Tink.Android (>= 1.7.0.1)    SpeechToText    E:\x\y\Demos\SpeechToText\SpeechToText\SpeechToText.csproj  1   
Error       Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'SpeechToText'.                
Error   NU1605  Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK from 1.3.230724000 to 1.2.221209.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 SpeechToText -> Microsoft.Maui.Essentials 8.0.3 -> Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK (>= 1.3.230724000) 
 SpeechToText -> Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK (>= 1.2.221209.1)  SpeechToText    E:\x\y\Demos\SpeechToText\SpeechToText\SpeechToText.csproj  1   
Error   NU1605  Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: Xamarin.AndroidX.Security.SecurityCrypto from 1.1.0.1-alpha06 to 1.1.0-alpha03. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 SpeechToText -> Microsoft.Maui.Essentials 8.0.3 -> Xamarin.AndroidX.Security.SecurityCrypto (>= 1.1.0.1-alpha06) 
 SpeechToText -> Xamarin.AndroidX.Security.SecurityCrypto (>= 1.1.0-alpha03)    SpeechToText    E:\x\y\Demos\SpeechToText\SpeechToText\SpeechToText.csproj  1   
Error   NU1605  Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.Maui.Graphics from 8.0.3 to 7.0.96. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 SpeechToText -> Microsoft.Maui.Essentials 8.0.3 -> Microsoft.Maui.Graphics (>= 8.0.3) 
 SpeechToText -> Microsoft.Maui.Graphics (>= 7.0.96)    SpeechToText    E:\x\y\Demos\SpeechToText\SpeechToText\SpeechToText.csproj  1   
Error   NU1605  Warning As Error: Detected package downgrade: Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser from 1.5.0.3 to 1.4.0.3. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 SpeechToText -> Microsoft.Maui.Essentials 8.0.3 -> Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser (>= 1.5.0.3) 
 SpeechToText -> Xamarin.AndroidX.Browser (>= 1.4.0.3)  SpeechToText    E:\x\y\Demos\SpeechToText\SpeechToText\SpeechToText.csproj  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your question, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcArg.png).

As the error shows:

> Error NU1605 Warning As Error: **Detected package downgrade**: .......

You need to update the corresponding packages. [But for some packages, the **Update** button is disabled and the following message appears: *Implicitly referenced by an SDK. To update the package, update the SDK to which it belongs.* This message indicates that the package is part of a larger framework or SDK and can't be updated independently.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#update-a-package)

That is also to say you need to use .net8. Create a project via .net 8, then you can install `Microsoft.Maui.Essentials` normally. For me, my version of VS is 17.5.5, updating to the latest version can fix the question:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try unchecking ***Treat Warnings as errors*** option from Project Properties and then attempt the installation again.

[image: Project Properties]

Alternatively, you can update all the affected Nuget packages and then reinstall Maui.Essentials. It is possible that the affected packages do not have the latest .net version supported, so please make sure that all the packages support .net 6 or above.

In case they don't, please follow these steps:

- Uninstall the package
- Install Maui.Essentials
- Reinstall the specific Nuget package.

Comment: Okie i Understood.. But it Alredy was unchecked by default & it it need to install for unitstalling did you talked about other packages?